# Flutter and Dart use without any other native language

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you build an app for IOS and WatchOS and the other Apple OSs, for their Android counterparts (phones, watches, tablets), for Desktops and the Web entirely in Flutter (Dart) for the Front-End, and then use a Back-End language like C/C++, Python or Go without using any native language like Swift, Kotlin or JavaScript? This really eases the development as you can use 2-3 languages for all the platforms.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "without using"? Do you want there not to **be** any of those languages anywhere in your project, or do you just not want to have to write code in those languages yourself?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, with the combination of `dart2native` and FFI, you could write runners in Dart for each platform instead of using the ones provided by `flutter create` which use standard platform languages. However:

- You'd lose the ability to use many of the features of the `flutter` tool, since you wouldn't be using the standard runners. On mobile you might be able to use parts of add-to-app, but on desktop you'd be entirely on your own for tooling.
- You wouldn't be able to use any plugins, since they are written in the platform languages and distributed as source.
- Your runners are still going to have to interact with platform-specific APIs, so even though you'll be writing in one language, you'll be writing different code on every platform.

So while what you want to do is almost certainly possible, it is going to make development **much** harder, not easier.

You mentioned that you don't know anything about Flutter; I suspect you think you need to write a lot more non-Dart code than you actually do. Many Flutter applications can be written without you ever needing to write a single line of code in the other languages you listed. I suggest trying it out to see if it's actually a problem you encounter before trying to reinvent a lot of wheels in Dart.